# Why is a gradient not a linear functional?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, definition

I'm reading this [book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=34Ic0K3LQxEC&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 104 they define:

[image]
[image]

Afterwards they said that if $m=1$, the function $f$ is real-valued and $T$ is the gradient which has to be a linear functional according to the definition.

The problem is this is not true in general, see for example:

$f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x,y)=\sin x$. The gradient is $\nabla f=(\cos x,0)$ which is not a linear functional.

Comment: Sloppily said. $T$ is the map $h \mapsto (\nabla f(a))\cdot h$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this multiplication the dot product?

Comment: Whatever inner product you have on the space. Typically it's the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The map $T$ is specific for each $x$. That is, for _each_ $x$ there is a linear map $T_x$ that fulfills the above limit. There is no restriction on what $T_{x+y}$ should be, specifically, no reason why it should be $T_x + T_y$.

Answer (score 4):

The gradient of $f$ is not lienar, but the gradient operator is linear.

i.e., $\nabla(f+g)=\nabla f+\nabla g$ and $\nabla cf =c\nabla f$

Comment: True, but this seems not to be what the OP asked about. I'd say that Daniel Fischer's comment clarifies things: the authors were most probably talking about the gradient of a function, evaluated at a point.

Comment: I do know that the gradient is linear. My doubt is why the dimension of its codomain is $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb R^2$ as my example shows.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the gradient at each point *should be* a linear functional for just this reason. What that means is that, if you think about it from a linear algebra perspective, is that the gradient is a *covector*, or dual vector, or row vector, i.e. it inhabits $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{*}$, because such a linear functional is the definition of a covector.

You can "check" this by thinking about how the gradient transforms when the input to $f$ is subject to a coordinate transformation. Namely, because of the chain rule, the gradient's components transform *covariantly*, instead of *contravariantly*; thus it must be a covector. In a sense, your elementary Calc text lied to you when it called this a vector (but not entirely - covectors *are* vectors, they just live in a different vector space than the things that are commonly called "vectors" at that stage. That's the "lie". However, the two spaces are isomorphic, so you can "ignore" this in a sense ... until you can't, as here.).